# Measure function execution time in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance

How do I measure function execution time, in milliseconds, in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 using the IDE? (not programmatically)

I'm programming in C++ without .NET

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You need to use profiling option provided by [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2017)